# Extracting Python DataFrame Column - Series vs DataFrame Retrieval

Tags: python, dataframe

I am struggling with a situation regarding retrieving dataframe column.

Say I have a DataFrame with one Column only.

```
df_Returns = pd.DataFrame(data = monthly_returns_array, columns = ['spx index'])
```

Now lets say,

```
col = df_Returns.columns
temp1 = df_Returns[col]
temp2 = df_Returns['spx index']
```

In my example above temp1 is being retrieved as DataFrame while temp2 is a series. Why is there this inconstancy?

My situation is that columns name in an original dataframe could be anything, so i would like to retrieves columns from another dataframe (with same column names as original) based on a loop on a variable rather than direct text.

I can convert the retrieved column from DataFrame to then Series, but I am just puzzled at this behavior.

Truly appreciate your help.

Comment: print `col` and you'll see that it's not the same as the string `"spx index"`. Perhaps also try `temp3 = df_Returns[['spx index']]`

Comment: Dataframe is stored in the memory as a collection of series. So when you do df_Returns['spx index'], it refers to the single column series.

Comment: @Deesha That is true but does not answer the question. The explanation is as simple as `df_Returns.columns` returns a list of all columns meaning `['spx index']` and not `spx index`  as pault wrote in his comment.